# Creating a Member Checklist

Tags: custom-fields

My site is powered by Zoo Visitor.  I need to set up an "at-a-glance" checklist for the members on there so they can see what they've completed and what they still need to do.  It would be nice if they could check what they've completed, but the admin would also have the option via the CP.  So a sample list might look like this:

```
DUE DATE          TASK                      COMPLETE
5/1/14          Purchase movie ticket          [ ]
5/1/14          Arrange for hotel              [ ]
5/5/14          Call for transportation        [ ]  
5/7/14          Purchase soft drink            [ ]
5/7/14          Purchase t-shirt               [ ]
etc
```

The list would be the same for all of the members, but obviously need to be separate for each.

Before I start working on creating a custom field, I wanted to make sure there wasn't something that would automatically take care of this.

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of it comes down to how you create the task list for the users.  Even though it is exactly the same for all members, will the items need to be changeable, etc?

It could be as simple as a channel form that submits the yes/no on each task in their list with entries going to a channel for "task statuses" or something like that.  Presumably you need your members to be able to update the status of the tasks asynchronously and therefore have the ability to return and change the status on items?  Once they have submitted a status for an item as complete do they have the ability to edit it after that?  Or does a "yes" status make the item uneditable going forward (i.e. what if something is the list falls through, for example)?

In a more complex scenario, I've done something like this with each individual task status being an entry (rather than all in a single entry), with the update occurring with Ajax and a modal window.  That let me handle the status for each independently and take different actions accordingly, especially since in some cases my checklist wasn't limited to yes/no.

I think you could accomplish this solidly with a channel form, but you'll have to map out the member interactions with the form a fair bit to determine which approach to editing will make the most sense.